# Entry point not found in .NET Core 2.0 DLL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I couldn't find anything that explains this -- for some reason my .NET Core 2.0 ASP.NET application does not run as a DLL via:

**dotnet MyProject.Web.dll**

And instead I get the exception:

**Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'MyProject.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.**

```
namespace MyProject.Web
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoadDependencies();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    } 

    private static void LoadDependencies()
    {
        DependencyLocator.Instance.DefineIfUndefined<IDataProvider, DataProvider>();
    }
}
}
```

It runs fine as a standalone executable (when targeting a "Console Application" in the project's config), but now that I'm trying to deploy to a server that needs it to run via the dotnet command (as a DLL, i.e. "dotnet .\MyProject.Web.dll"), it seems to be having issues.  I get the above exception on both my server and my local development box.

I'm kind of blown away that it cannot locate the Main method -- it's declared as static and in Program.cs.  Am I missing something?

(EDIT: To clarify, the DLL I'm trying to run against the "dotnet" command is from the target compiling as a "Console Library," since my server is explicitly asking for a DLL, since they will not run executables).

Comment: I am really confused by your question. The main function is required for console application and as per your code, when you run on standalone then you are running console. Please share the reason for deploying on the server.

Comment: When I try running the application via dotnet MyProject.Web.dll, I get an Exception, as specified above.  If I compile locally and have it run as an Application, it runs/works just fine.  However, our server environment requires our web stuff to be deployed/run as DLL's thru the dotnet command.  When I run the DLL thru dotnet, it does NOT work, and that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, so this is annoying and will hopefully help someone else out.

My host wants to specifically run DLL's thru .NET Core ONLY.  They do not allow for executables to be run.

Because DLL's are frequently built as "Class Library" output types on the project, I assumed that this was the workflow necessary to build it.  However, I found out that whenever you build your project as a "Console Application," it builds a DLL in addition to an EXE.  So, in the above example, MyProject.Web.exe and MyProject.Web.dll are both built when the output type is "Console Application."

MyProject.Web.dll that comes from "Console Application" is different than MyProject.Web.Dll that comes from "Class Library."  The one that comes from "Class Library" **will NOT** have an entry point that can be discovered on it, which will lead to the problem above.

So, if you're getting this error, look for the DLL that ships with your EXE of the same name -- that's the actual DLL you'll want to run in your dotnet console (i.e. dotnet MyProject.Web.dll)

Comment: Both the question and the answer are ambiguous. How come you get an .exe while others get .dll? It won't help others in its current status.

Comment: @LexLi Don't know if you're the down voter but you shouldn't have if so. I ran into same exact problem. i thought I could make in a Console App to get rid of exe file and assumed dll output would be the same. Had no idea this was the issue. This answer definitely helped me.

Comment: Same here - answer saved me hours of potential frustration

Comment: Helped me out as well... Had this error only under windows during debugging. Had no problem with the "Class Library" Property under Linux in Prod environment.

Comment: @Locke did you found a solution for this, i am getting the same issue on aws  elastic beanstalk, its not a clean solution to use console app when all we want is class libraries

Comment: @user2650277 - did you read the solution?  Basically, you'll need to build it as a Console App, and then use the "DLL" with the same name -- so if you have your project as a Console app and it's called "MyProject.exe", look for the "MyProject.dll" -- the "MyProject.dll" is the item you want.

Comment: @Locke I found a better solution check my answer

Comment: While that may be what AWS needs, that's not necessarily what every host needs.

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional digging based on @Locke answer and was able to find a solution for class libraries.You need to add a `Procfile` in your zip that you upload to ElasticBeanstalk so that EB knows which DLL contain the entry point. That DLL will typically be the console app while any other projects in the solution would be class libaries.

Suppose `MyProject.Web.dll` is the Console App , `Procfile` should have the following content.

`web: dotnet MyProject.Web.dll`